# Can I have an azure website be a virtual in the same domain as my azure cloud service

Tags: azure

Hope I explain this clearly enough. I am migrating a web application to azure. I have it setup so far as an aspx web application and a sql server database. The site is hosted (don't know if that's the correct term) in a cloud service (which I deployed using Visual Studio). Everything works great so far. What I want to do now is add a WP blog. I have created on as a test and it's really easy as an azure website.

What I want to do is this: If my custom domain is www.site.com and that points to the cloud service web role, can I create a WP blog as a separate azure website at myblog.azurewebsites.net and somehow point a virtual at that so that www.site.com/blog will point to the blog website? I know how to add a domain to the website, just not sure how to do the virtual part...

Thanks for any suggestions!
-Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, NO, unless you can modify the BLOG's code to keep rewriting URL's to make it look like www.site.com/blog

Simpler alternative: implement a blog.site.com instead of www.site.com/blog and map it to your blog on Azure sites.  You can also setup a redirect to work from www.site/com/blog to go to blog.site.com

Comment: Using a subdomain is the answer I think! I wonder if it would be cheaper to then just move the whole site from cloud services to a website so I can run the whole thing from the same type of technology. At least from a maintenance standpoint, it might be easier. I'll have to look into that. Thanks!! -J

Comment: It's a good idea, but just be careful, Azure websites do not support SSL right now.  Also, the permissions under which Web Roles run are somewhat less restrictive then Websites

Comment: So then I am back to square one! I jsut want to host an asp.net website and a WP blog. Something simple in a shared hosting environment. Is there a way to make it happen while supporting SSL at least for the non-blog content?

Comment: Not until Microsoft implements SSL support on Websites.